# PHP Key name array

Tags: php, regex, arrays, key, rename

I have an array $data

```
 fruit => apple,
 seat => sofa,
```

etc. I want to loop through so that each key becomes type_key[0]['value'] so eg

```
 type_fruit[0]['value'] => apple,
 type_seat[0]['value'] => sofa,
```

and what I thought would do this, namely

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value)
{
        # Create a new, renamed, key. 
        $array[str_replace("/(.+)/", "type_$1[0]['value']", $key)] = $value;

        # Destroy the old key/value pair
        unset($array[$key]);

}

print_r($array);
```

Doesn't work. How can I make it work?

Also, I want everything to be in the keys (not the values) to be lowercase: is there an easy way of doing this too? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting here. You want the KEY to look like `type_fruit[0]['value']`, so you can access it using `$array["type_fruit[0]['value']"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to make the keys into separate arrays? Or did you mean to just change the keys in the same array?

```
    $array = array();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $array['type_' . strtolower($key)] = array(array('value' => $value));
    }
```

if you want your keys to be separate variables, then do this:

```
    extract($array);
```

Now you will have $type_fruit and $type_sofa. You can find your values as $type_fruit[0]['value'], since we put an extra nested array in there.

Comment: Don't forget to strtolower() the keys :)

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements sound... suspect. Perhaps you meant something like the following:

```
$arr = array('fruit' => 'apple', 'seat' => 'sofa');
$newarr = array();

foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
{
  $newkey = strtolower("type_$key");
  $newarr[$newkey] = array(array('value' => $value));
}

var_dump($newarr);
```

Answer (score 0):

First I wouldn't *alter* the input-array but create a new one unless you're in serious, serious trouble with your memory limit.
And then you can't simply replace the key to add a deeper nested level to an array.
`$x[ 'abc[def]' ]` is still only referencing a top-level element, since `abc[def]` is parsed as one string, but you want `$x['abc']['def']`.

```
$data = array(
 'fruit' => 'apple',
 'seat' => 'sofa'
);

$result = array();

foreach($data as $key=>$value) {
  $target = 'type_'.$key; 
  // this might be superfluous, but who knows... if you want to process more than one array this might be an issue.
  if ( !isset($result[$target]) || !is_array($result[$target]) ) {
    $result[$target] = array();
  }
  $result[$target][] = array('value'=>$value);
}

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score -1):

for starters

```
$array[str_replace("/(.+)/", "type_$1[0]['value']", $key)] = $value;
```

should be

```
$array[str_replace("/(.+)/", type_$1[0]['value'], $key)] = $value;
```

Comment: Are you kidding me? You just broke further his call to str_replace instead of using preg_replace to fix it.

Comment: "type_$1[0]['value']" will be treated as a string so type_$1[0]['value'] will return the value he is looking for ( altough i agree he is using the wrong function )

Comment: No, it's not. There's a `$` in the middle of it. It's just a very good way to get a `syntax error: unexpected $`. Besides, how/why is that better? Even if it worked, using string literals without quotes emits a notice telling it _shouldn't_ be done.